# How to access a specific property as a parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, parameter-passing

A simple class is given:

```
class Point {
  public x: number;
  public y: number;
  …
}
```

A specific property of the class should be accessed as a parameter. In JavaScript this is quickly formulated as follows:

```
let p = new Point();

function getXorY(xy) {
  return p[xy]; // like p["x"] instead of p.x
}

console.log(getXorY("x"));
```

But how is this implemented in TypeScript?

I have searched thoroughly for an answer. Since I couldn't think of any suitable keywords, unfortunately without success.

On the way to a possible solution to the problem, I stumbled across "keyof" - but without getting any closer to the solution.

Please do not rate the example in terms of its usefulness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `getXorY` like this:

```
function getXorY(xy: keyof Point) {
  return p[xy]
}
```

you'll be able to pass only `'x'` or `'y'` to it

Comment: A complex issue (for me and for others), clearly explained. Many Thanks!